# Recommended defconfig options for normal use

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compile

I have chrooted Debian on a router arm. Now, a lot of packages I try require kernel options that have not been enabled. Obviously I have the firmware source code and the ability to recompile the kernel, and I actually know that the default kconfig is very minimal. Now the first disabled option that limits the usage is config_epool, so I can proceed to enable it and recompile everything... But I'm worried about having to find other options later that normally in a kernel shipped with Debian would be enabled and I don't like having recompile everything every time.

So I wonder what options it is recommended to enable when doing a normal use like in the precompiled distro kernels.

Comment: "_normally in a kernel shipped with Debian_" - Debian don't just take the upstream / mainline kernel sources, compile, package and distribute... they [maintain a set of patches](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-kernel-handbook/ch-source.html) on top of the upstream kernel as well... Ideally, you'd use a Debian kernel with Debian userspace. But you could try taking a config from one of their packages and using that...?

Comment: @Attie A defconfig is full of architecture-dependent options, selinux etc ... Should I see the documentation for each option? I wonder if there is a list of generic options that should be enabled in each distro.

Comment: Correct. Debian's ARM config will be available from their package repo!